# Unable to do mysqldump to AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-ec2, mysql, rds

I'm trying to export an existing MySQL DB from an AWS EC2 instance to RDS using mysqldump. Here's my syntax:

> mysqldump wordpress-db | mysql --host= --port=3306 --user= --password wordpress-db

...where wordpress-db is an existing MySQL DB on my EC2 instance and wordpress-db is also the name of the RDS DB (the endpoint begins with "wordpress-db").

The error message is:

> ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'wordpress-db'
>   Both the EC2 instance and RDS DB are in the same region...

I'm a bit new to RDS so there's probably something obvious I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?
Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Try this: **`mysqldump -h<Hostname> --port=3306 -u<useranme> -p wordpress-db > wordpress-db.sql`**

Comment: Where will the file be dumped? I am using  Secure Shell to run this command.

Comment: with above command, file will be dumped in your present working directory.

Answer (score 1):

The form of invocation you're using requires that the database already exist on the target server.

A better approach is to add `--databases` immediately before the database name on the `mysqldump` side of the pipe.  Then remove the name of the database from the `mysql` side of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answers! This saved some of the few hairs I had left on my head. Here's the final syntax I used:

> mysqldump -u username -p --databases wordpress-db | mysql --host=RDS-endpoint --port=3306 --user=username --password=password

Thanks!